# How to map multiple sources into single destination member

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm trying to map multiple sources of different types into a single destination using AutoMapper, but the destination gets overwritten with whatever the last property was that was mapped (Wire in my example below). How can I append to the destination list instead of having it being overwritten? This is how I have currently registered my mappings:

```
CreateMap<SourceBE, Destination()
   .ForMember(e => e.Payments, c => c.MapFrom(src => src.Checks))
   .ForMember(e => e.Payments, c => c.MapFrom(src => src.Wires))
   ;

CreateMap<CheckBE, Destination>()
   .ForMember(e => e.Id, c => c.MapFrom(src => src.Id))
   .ForMember(e => e.Amount, c => c.MapFrom(src => src.Amount))
   .ForMember(e => e.Type, c => c.MapFrom(src => PaymentType.Check))
   ;

CreateMap<WireBE, Destination>()
   .ForMember(e => e.Id, c => c.MapFrom(src => src.Id))
   .ForMember(e => e.Amount, c => c.MapFrom(src => src.Amount))
   .ForMember(e => e.Type, c => c.MapFrom(src => PaymentType.Wire))
   ;
```

I could introduce a base type that all payments share and then concatenate the lists, is there any other way to just add on the destination list?

Comment: When mapping to an existing collection, the destination collection is cleared first. If this is not what you want, take a look at [AutoMapper.Collection](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Collection).

Comment: Hi, I have come across that before, in what way would that changed my mapping? Would you be able to provide an example?

Comment: Checks the docs and the tests in the repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving my issue with AfterMap().

```
.AfterMap((src, dest, ctx) =>
{
   var checks = ctx.Mapper.Map<IList<Destination>>(src.Checks);
   var wires = ctx.Mapper.Map<IList<Destination>>(src.Wires);
   dest.Payments = checks.Concat(wires).ToList();
});
```

The only downside I found with this approach is that you can no longer use ProjectTo<>() because it doesn't support AfterMap().

So instead of this:

```
.ProjectTo<Destination>()
```

Just do this:

```
Mapper.Map<Destination>(sourceBE)
```

As mentioned by Lucian AutoMapper.Collection might be an alternative approach. After consulting the docs I didn't really see how this would help my problem, and even if it did how it would be better than using AfterMap.